# Need help playing songs in my music player component

Tags: reactjs

I've created a music player component for a project I'm working on but I can't seem to get it to play the array of songs that I'm passing it too.

It worked fine when I just passed it the mp3 files from within the same component but it doesn't work now since I am passing it an object instead. I think I may be destructuring it wrong when I'm receiving the props.

Any help is appreciated!

```js
import React from 'react'

//Components
import MusicPlayer from '../components/MusicPlayer';

//Song Images 
import Drake from '../images/Drake.jpg'
import Adelle from '../images/adelle.png'
import Elvis from '../images/Elvis_hounddog.jpg'

//Song files
import DrakeOneDance from '../music/Drake_One_Dance.mp3'
import AdelleHello from '../music/Adele_Hello.mp3'
import ElvisHoundDog from '../music/Elvis.mp3'

//Song array 

const songs = [
  
  {
    artist: 'Drake',
    songName: 'One Dance',
    poster: Drake,
    songFile: DrakeOneDance
  },
  {
    artist: 'Adelle',
    songName: 'Hello',
    poster: Adelle,
    songFile: AdelleHello
  },
  {
    artist: 'Elvis',
    songName: 'Hound Dog',
    poster: Elvis,
    songFile: ElvisHoundDog
  },

]


function Music() {

    return (

      <div className='music-container'>
          <MusicPlayer songs={songs}/>
      </div>
     
    );
  }

  export default Music
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

// MUI ICONS
import { Slider } from '@mui/material';
import SkipPreviousIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SkipPrevious';
import SkipNextIcon from '@mui/icons-material/SkipNext';
import PlayArrowIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PlayArrow';
import PauseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Pause';
import VolumeDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeDown';
import VolumeUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeUp';
import VolumeOffIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeOff';
import VolumeMuteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeMute';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton'

// This is what I was initially passing it

//Music 
// import Elvis from '../music/Elvis.mp3'
// import Fade from '../music/Fade.mp3' 
// import Drake from '../music/Drake_One_Dance.mp3'


// const playList = [Drake, Elvis, Fade]



function MusicPlayer({songs}) {

    //Song Files
    const songFiles = songs.songFile;

    
    //Hooks
    const audioPlayer = useRef()

    //State
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
    const [currentSong] = useState(songFiles[index]);
    const [isPlaying, setisPlaying] = useState(false);
    const [volume, setVolume] = useState(30);
    const [mute, setMute] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(audioPlayer) {
            audioPlayer.current.volume = volume / 100;
        }
    }, [volume]);


    function togglePlay() {
        if(!isPlaying) {
            audioPlayer.current.play()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.current.pause()
        }
        // setisPlaying(prev => !prev)
        setisPlaying(isPlaying => !isPlaying)
    }

    function toggleSkipForward() {
        if(index >= songFiles.length - 1) {
            setIndex(0);
            audioPlayer.current.src = songFiles[0];
            audioPlayer.current.play();
        } else {
            setIndex(prev => prev + 1);
            audioPlayer.current.src = songFiles[index + 1];
            audioPlayer.current.play();
        }
    }


    function toggleSkipBackward() {
        if(index > 0) {
            setIndex(prev => prev -1);
            audioPlayer.current.src = songFiles[index -1];
            audioPlayer.current.play();
        } 
    }
    
    

    function VolumeBtns() {
        return mute
            ? <VolumeOffIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            : volume <= 20 ? <VolumeMuteIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            : volume <= 75 ? <VolumeDownIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            : <VolumeUpIcon sx={{color: 'lime', '&:hover': {color: 'white'}}} onClick={() => setMute(!mute)} />
            }



  return (


    <div className='music-player-container'>

    <audio src={currentSong} ref={audioPlayer} muted={mute} />    

        <div className="controls">

            <div className="volume">

                <IconButton>
                    <VolumeBtns />
                </IconButton>

                 <Slider min={0} max={100} value={volume} onChange={(e,v) => setVolume(v)}
                defaultValue={50}
                    sx={{
                    width: 100,
                    color: 'success.main',
                    margin: '20px',
                    }} /> 
            </div>

            <div className="control-panel">

                    <IconButton onClick={toggleSkipBackward}>
                        <SkipPreviousIcon
                        sx={{
                            margin: '10px',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'}
                        }} />
                    </IconButton>

                    {/* Play/Pause */}
                
                {!isPlaying
                  ?  <IconButton onClick={togglePlay}>
                        <PlayArrowIcon sx={{ margin: '10px', cursor: 'pointer', color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'} }} />
                    </IconButton>
                    
                   : <IconButton onClick={togglePlay}>
                        <PauseIcon sx={{ margin: '10px', cursor: 'pointer', color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'} }} />
                    </IconButton>
                }
                    
                    {/* Play/Pause */}


                    <IconButton onClick={toggleSkipForward}>
                        <SkipNextIcon
                        sx={{
                            margin: '10px',
                            cursor: 'pointer',
                            color: 'silver', '&:hover': {color: 'blue'}
                        }} />
                    </IconButton>

            </div>
        </div>
                         
            
    </div>


  )
}

export default MusicPlayer
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that `songs` array doesn't have a `songFile` property

```
const songFiles = songs.map(song => song.songFile)
```